# Multiple column foreign key referencing on the same key from a table

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I have this:

```
Table "schedules"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| sched_id | sched_name | sc_id1 | sc_id2 | sc_id3 | sc_id4 | sc_id5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |  block 1   |   1    |    2   |   3    |    4   |    5   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2     |  block 2   |   1    |    2   |   3    |  NULL  |  NULL  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Table "subject_current"
---------------------------------------
|sc_id | sl_id | schoolyear | semister|
---------------------------------------
|   1  |   5   | 2014-2015  |    1st  |
---------------------------------------
|   2  |   6   | 2014-2015  |    1st  |
---------------------------------------
|   3 |    7   | 2014-2015  |    1st  |
---------------------------------------
|   4  |   8   | 2014-2015  |    1st  |
---------------------------------------
|   5  |   9   | 2014-2015  |    1st  |
---------------------------------------

Table "subject_list"
-------------------------------------------------------------
|sl_id | subject_code | subject_description | subject_prereq|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   5  |      math1   |         algebra     |      none     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   6  |      math2   |    trigonometry     |      none     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   7  |      math3   |        Calculus     |      none     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   8  |      eng1    |       english 1     |      none     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   9  |      hum1    |      humanities     |      none     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Column **sc_id1 - sc_id5** is a foreign key referencing to the same key which is **sc_id** from table **subject_current**. And column **sl_id** from table **subject_current** is referencing to **sl_id** from table **subject_list**.

My question is, how can I retrieve the data from `table` **subject_list** using only the data from `table` **schedules**? What I want to achieve is like this:

```
(This will echo on my page)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| sched_id | sched_name |                       Subjects                       | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |   block 1  | algebra, tirgonometry, calculus, english1, humanities|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2     |   block 2  |          algebra, tirgonometry, calculus             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've search about `LEFT JOIN` but it's kinda hard for me because I'm just a beginner in this field and there's three `tables` that may have to `JOIN`. So please if you can tip some advice I gladly appreciate that.

**EDITED**

I've found this and I'm almost there, but it only shows the first `sc_id` from table **schedule_subject_currents**:

```
    <?php

    echo "<table class='opensubtbl' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' ><tr>";

    echo "<th>Schedule ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Sched Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Subjects ID</th></tr>";

    //$sched = mysql_query("select * from schedules s, schedule_subject_currents h, subject_current c, subject_list l where s.sched_id = h.sched_id and h.sc_id = c.sc_id and c.sl_id = l.sl_id");
    //$sched = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedules");

    $sched = mysql_query("

        SELECT *
        FROM schedules s
        LEFT JOIN schedule_subject_currents ssc ON ssc.sched_id = s.sched_id
        LEFT JOIN subject_current c ON c.sc_id = ssc.sc_id
        LEFT JOIN subject_list l ON l.sl_id = c.sl_id
        GROUP BY s.sched_id, sched_name
        ORDER BY sched_name

    ");

    while($rows_s = mysql_fetch_assoc($sched)){
        $s_schedid = $rows_s['sched_id'];
        $s_schedname = $rows_s['sched_name'];
        $s_subdesc = $rows_s['subject_description'];
        $s_scid = $rows_s['sc_id'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$s_schedid</td>";
        echo "<td>$s_schedname</td>";

        echo "<td>$s_subdesc</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: @FabioCardoso, thanks for response sir. But sched_id won't match sc_id. Imagine you have a schedule with a lot of subject ids, and that subject ids holds data from another table.

Comment: columns like `idn` smells, you need to normalize it by creating other table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid storing the same kind of information in different columns, otherwise you end up with problems like the one you have encountered. Instead you should store each piece of information in its own row.

First, normalize your data schema by introducing another table called *e.g.* scedule_subject_currents, so that you have

```
Table "schedules"
-------------------------
| sched_id | sched_name |
-------------------------
|    1     |  block 1   | 
-------------------------
|    2     |  block 2   | 
-------------------------
```

and

```
Table "schedule_subject_currents"
--------------------
| sched_id | sc_id |
--------------------
|    1     |  1    |
--------------------
|    1     |  2    |
--------------------
|    1     |  3    |
--------------------
|    1     |  4    |
--------------------
|    1     |  5    |
--------------------
|    2     |  1    |
--------------------
|    2     |  2    |
--------------------
|    2     |  3    |
--------------------
```

Then you can use the query

```
SELECT s.sched_id, s.sched_name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject_description) as Subjects
FROM schedules s
LEFT JOIN schedule_subject_currents ssc ON ssc.sched_id = s.sched_id
LEFT JOIN subject_current c ON c.sc_id = ssc.sc_id
LEFT JOIN subject_list l ON l.sl_id = c.sl_id
GROUP BY s.sched_id, sched_name
ORDER BY sched_name
```

Comment: Wow! This makes sense to me now. This will be a good practice for me from now on. But I'm bothered about the "Subjects", "subjects", "sced_id" and "sced_name". "sced_id" and "sced_name" maybe a typo error. But the "Subjects" and/or "subjects", I don't get it. Where did you did that? I'm confused.

Comment: I already tried you query and change something to make it work but it only displays the first `sc_id` from table **schedule_subject_currents**. And if I remove the `GROUP BY` this will display all `sc_id`s. But I want it to be grouped and look like the table on my question.

Comment: @ArchieZineg When you get a query & schema working for you from this answer be sure to unaccept the other ugly non-relational answer and accept this one.

Comment: @Archie Zineg If you get only one sc_id for each sched_id, it sounds like you have omitted the `GROUP_CONCAT`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4946d/1/0 for a demo of the corrected query. (sced_id should be sched_id, sced_name should be sched_name, and subject s should be schedules s).

Answer (score 1):

Try `while` nesting your query:

```
<?php

    echo "<table class='opensubtbl' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' ><tr>";

    echo "<th>Schedule ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Sched Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Subjects</th>";
    echo "<th></th></tr>";

    //$sched = mysql_query("select * from schedules s, schedule_subject_currents h, subject_current c, subject_list l where s.sched_id = h.sched_id and h.sc_id = c.sc_id and c.sl_id = l.sl_id");
    //$sched = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedules");
    //$sched = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedules s LEFT JOIN schedule_subject_currents ssc ON ssc.sched_id = s.sched_id LEFT JOIN subject_current c ON c.sc_id = ssc.sc_id LEFT JOIN subject_list l ON l.sl_id = c.sl_id ORDER BY sched_name ");

    $sched = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedules");

    while($rows_s = mysql_fetch_assoc($sched)){
        $s_schedid = $rows_s['sched_id'];
        $s_schedname = $rows_s['sched_name'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$s_schedid</td>";
        echo "<td>$s_schedname</td>";
        echo "<td>";

        $schedsubcur = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedule_subject_currents WHERE sched_id='$s_schedid'");
        while($rows_ssc = mysql_fetch_assoc($schedsubcur)){
            $ssc_scid = $rows_ssc['sc_id'];
            $schedsublist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_current WHERE sc_id='$ssc_scid'");
            while($rows_ssl = mysql_fetch_assoc($schedsublist)){
                $ssl_slid = $rows_ssl['sl_id'];
                $ssublist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject_list WHERE sl_id='$ssl_slid'");
                while($rows_ssubl = mysql_fetch_assoc($ssublist)){
                    $ssubl_subdesc = $rows_ssubl['subject_description'];
                    echo $ssubl_subdesc."($ssc_scid), ";
                }
            }
        }

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

?>
```